# Could not load file or assembly "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common, Version=12.0.21005.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2015, tfs

I keep getting the exception message `Could not load file or assembly "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common, Version=12.0.21005.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a` when I try to connect to my TFS server (using C#) while using the below piece of code:

```
Uri tfsUri = (args.Length < 1) ? 
new Uri("http://Server:Port/VDir") : new Uri(args[0]);
TfsConfigurationServer configurationServer = TfsConfigurationServerFactory.GetConfigurationServer(tfsUri);
```

The code is referred from:

*https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb286958(v=vs.120).aspx*

Could not find this `dll` - "**Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common**" in my local system nor over the internet.

Can you please help on what am I missing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I tested with the piece of code, eveything works as expected.

So, how did you create the project? Have you installed the Nuget packages : [Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient/)

If not yet, just try to install it in`Package Manager Console`, then check it again.

[image]

Comment: @andyHey, The solution provided by you was really helpful. It did resolve my issue. Thank you so much.

Comment: @andy-li-msft I don't know how you knew that, but YES!